# What is by.js locator for in Protractor/WebDriverJS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Recently, I've noticed a new locator being added to the Protractor documentation - the [`by.js()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.js):

> Locates an elements by evaluating a JavaScript expression, which may be either a function or a string.

I understand what this locator provides, but I am missing the *real-world use cases* when this locator can be useful. When should I prefer to use `by.js` instead of other built-in locators like `by.css`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I feel the use case is to get elements using core javascript functions, whenever `css` and other element locators won't help or are don't have properties that we could use. Scenarios -

1. If you are getting an element using core javascript functions passing it to `browser.executeScript` then `by.js` can be used to replace it.

**Example: -**

Suppose if you had to get an element that appears on top between the two, you could get it this way -

```
var ele = element(by.js(function(){
    var ele1 = document.getElementById('#ele1');
    var ele2 = document.getElementById('#ele2');
    var val = ele1.compareDocumentPosition(ele2);
    if(val === 4) return ele1;
    else return ele2;
}));
```

2. If you want to get element using its css values like color, font, etc... Though `filter` can be used in this case, but `by.js` also supports it.
3. If the elements are not accessible by *css* or *xpath* or any other locators, for example *pseudo-elements* that have animations or transitions.

**Example:** -

Suppose if there's element which has `:before` and `:after` transitions -

```
.element:before {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

To verify the color of the element, we could use `by.js` passing in a javascript statement to get the element -

```
var ele = element(by.js(function(){
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.element'), ':before');
}));
expect(ele.getCssValue('color')).toEqual('rgb(255, 0, 0)');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting use cases, now I can imagine where could I have used `by.js`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think the cases for this are pretty slim, but I can see this being of use when there's data on the client that is not available (or unreliably so) through selenium.

The example on the docs page includes a reference to `offsetWidth`:

```
spans[i].offsetWidth > 100
```

Used in context:

```
var wideElement = element(by.js(function() {
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
    if (spans[i].offsetWidth > 100) {
     return spans[i];
    }
  }
}));
expect(wideElement.getText()).toEqual('Three');
```

Alternatively, there may be a use case if there's a third party API on the window or some other service that can help locate an element.